# How to include the detection of C language keywords when creating a User Defined Language

Tags: c, notepad++

I'm trying to create a UDL to use with Notepad++. The goal is to have a UDL that is basically the result of joining all the C syntax with some special keywords that are used by a certain program.

The problem is that the way the UDL definition is done now doesn't allow to proper implement the detection of keywords in C, due to the lack of blank spaces in between them.

[I can't obtain the recognition of this keywords with my UDL defined language](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0den3.png)

I tried to copy the stylers.xml and langs.xml keywords and styles nodes related to the C language to my UDL .xml file, but it doesn't seem to work.

Can anyone please tell me if there is a way to achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got an answer!

One can copy C keywords from langs.xml file (directly into UDL GUI), but you can't copy styling. Instead one must manually setup styling to mimic built-in C styler:

[definition of C keywords](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wQzyu.png)

As for the blank spaces, code like this:

if(condition)

does not consist of two keywords, it consists of four keywords. One needs to define each one of them before UDL can decipher it:

Keywords: if condition

Operators: ( )

[definition of operators](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ri6FD.png)

Once one tells to UDL what braces are, Notepad++ is able to correctly highlight all the keywords.

Credits to Loreia L. for the answer

Answer (score 0):

If you're just looking to add keywords to the C styles, you might just want to add custom keywords.  In the style configurator, the TYPE WORD and INSTRUCTION WORD styles have a section for user-defined keywords.

To my knowledge, UDLs in Notepad++ are not as full-featured as built-in languages.  They use a more rudimentary system for syntax highlighting, and are more limited.  I doubt you'll be able to replicate the C highlighting, even if you work with the XML files directly.  Hopefully the custom keywords are good enough for what you're using.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, Owen. That would be a not ideal but manageable solution if the keywords were case sensitive, but as the custom keywords I want to introduce are not case sensitive, and we can not set them as such in the style configurator, I'm afraid the solution involving the style configurator won't work for me.
I guess I'll just have to set one as the main language, and use the other one when wanting to check the code.